# c5 Filemanager and TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

**Getting closer if anyone is interested** c5 Filebrowser is looking pretty cool if I can get it all to work!

I’ve got the “Browse” button to appear on the TimyMCE > Insert/Edit Image popup to appear by adding the following to the **tinymce_jquery_full.cshtml** file

```
function myFileBrowser (field_name, url, type, win) {

var cmsURL = "../../Filemanager/index.html"

tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
    file : cmsURL,
    title : 'Browser',
    width : 800,  // Your dimensions may differ - toy around with them!
    height : 500,
    resizable : "yes",
    inline : "yes",  // This parameter only has an effect if you use the inlinepopups plugin!
    close_previous : "no"
}, {
    window : win,
    input : field_name
});
return false;
}
```

and

```
file_browser_callback : 'myFileBrowser',
```

Just add it all inside the main

```
<script type="text/javascript"> tag
```

and it works fine

With this button c5 Filebrowser opens and I can play with it as normal.

What I can tell is that c5 filebrowser is set up to work with CKEditor and not TimyMCE so this is where I am having trouble

I then followed the following instructions at this link:

http://forum.filemanager.corefive.com/topic/how-do-i-get-a-value-back-from-the-filemanager-for-the-selected-file

Which shows me how to get the 'Select' buttons to show in Filemanager and some other info that doesn't work for me.

If I add the recommended code:

```
var selectItem = function (data) {
    var p = data['Path'];
    alert(p);
    $('#field_name', window.opener.document).val(p);
    window.close();
}
```

To filemanager.js, I can get **alert(p);** to work, it gives me the URL sting to the image i'm after, but the window wont close let alone the value of 'p' posting back to the TinyMCE popups field.

So I now have two javascript popups open one on top of the other, but on Select of image in Filemanager, I need filemanger to close and the value of 'p' to be passed back to 'scr' field of TimyMCE's "Insert/Edit Image" popup form.

Tough to explain!

Calling all Javascript wizards for help?

**Original Post Below**

Does anyone know of a tutorial on how to integrate c5 Filemanager (http://forum.filemanager.corefive.com/#home) and TinyMCE, I’ve done some searching but I can’t find much! I’d like to add a browse button to the Insert/Edit image popup on TinyMCE that would then open filemanager and populate on click the image URL field with the images URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, it’s all here at the TinyMCE site:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/How-to_implement_a_custom_file_browser

I just didn’t look far enough down the page, I guess because I was surprised that TinyMCE would give so much help on the issue.

```
var selectItem = function(data){
    var url = relPath + data['Path'];

    if(window.tinyMCEPopup){
        // use TinyMCE > 3.0 integration method
        var win = tinyMCEPopup.getWindowArg("window");
        win.document.getElementById(tinyMCEPopup.getWindowArg("input")).value = url;
        if (typeof(win.ImageDialog) != "undefined") {
            // Update image dimensions
            if (win.ImageDialog.getImageData)
                win.ImageDialog.getImageData();

            // Preview if necessary
            if (win.ImageDialog.showPreviewImage)
                win.ImageDialog.showPreviewImage(url);
        }
        tinyMCEPopup.close();
        return;
    }
}
```

The code is already there in filemanager.js, you just have to remove all the if(window.opener){ code and it all works perfectly!

For all the guys at c5 filemanager and TinyMCE, love your work!